# How to setup bare git repository on localhost from existing project?

Tags: git, localhost, repository

I have a new project I am working on and I already created a git repository for this project/directory. The project is on my machine in my office that is always running and reachable.
Now I wanted to create a bare repository from it that I can use as a "server" to copy from/to from my home machine via ssh. I tried

```
git clone --bare project project.git
```

It created a bare repository from my working directory but there are no remotes or branches set to the new bare repo. But when I switch to the new repo

```
git remote -v
```

gives me

```
origin /home/auron/project (fetch)
origin /home/auron/project (push)
```

That's basically just the other way around than I wanted it. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

> [`git clone --bare`] created a bare repository from my working directory but there are no remotes or branches set to [make the original Git use] the new bare repo ...

That's quite normal.

When you make a clone, your Git remembers where it cloned *from*.  It does not modify the *source* at all; it makes a new repository, more or less as if you ran the following sequence of commands:

```
mkdir new-repo.git
cd new-repo.git
git init <flags>
git remote add origin <url>
...
```

(where `<flags>` represents the `--bare` flag, and `<url>` represents the URL from which you are cloning).

If you want to affect some *existing* repository:

```
cd existing-repository
git remote add <name> <url>
```

where `<name>` is the name you want to use—maybe `origin`, for instance—and `<url>` is the URL you want to associate with that name.

Note that this merely adds a *name*, without first contacting the given URL to see if there is a Git at the given URL.  So if you have a typo here your next `git fetch` will fail, when it tries to use the URL.

Note also then when you make your initial bare clone, you may want to use the `--mirror` option, if the source from which you are cloning has more than one branch.  You may or may not want to run `git remote remove origin` *in* the bare clone afterward, to remove from the clone its memory of where it came from.  (In normal operation, remembering is harmless, but (a) if you used `--mirror` and (b) someone tries to run `git fetch` *in* the bare clone, this could be bad.)